# How to display entered password when click "?" Button

Tags: titanium

I am using password field in titanium iPhone application, I need to display entered password if user press "?" button and mask password field after release "?" button. I used these code

```
var password = Ti.UI.createTextField
({
   font : {fontSize : 15, fontType: 'HaveticaL TStd', fontWeight: 'roman'},
   hintText: "***************",
   top : 54,
   left : 107,
   height : 24,
   width : 153,
   passwordMask : true,
   color : "black",
   returnKeyType : Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE,
   zIndex : 5
});
```

I used touchstart and touchend event for showing password, i.e. set passwordMask to false when touchstart event is occurred and reset to true when touchend event occurred.

```
passwordHintImg.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e){
    passwordTxt.passwordMask = false;
});
passwordHintImg.addEventListener('touchend',function(e){
    passwordTxt.passwordMask = true;
});
```

It works good when password field is blur, but if password field is focused I press "?" button the password is shown and I cannot able to hide showed password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got the output

I used label for showing password and set visible to false, when touchstart event occur I changed passwordShow Label visible to true and set password field visble to disable, when touchend event occur I reset password field visible to true and passwordShow label visible to false.

```
var passwordShow = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    font : {fontSize : 15, fontType: 'HaveticaL TStd', fontWeight: 'roman'},
    top : 54,
    left : 107,
    height : 24,
    width : 153,
    visible : false,
    backgroundColor : 'transparent',
    color : "black",
    zIndex : 15
});
passwordShowVw.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e){
    if(passwordTxt.value.length > 0)
    {
        passwordTxt.visible = false;
        passwordShow.visible = true;
        passwordShow.text = passwordTxt.value;  
    }
});
passwordShowVw.addEventListener('touchend',function(e){
    if(passwordTxt.value.length > 0)
    {
         passwordShow.visible = false;
         passwordTxt.visible = true;
         passwordShow.text = '';
    }
});
```